# Orbeon Xforms nested repeats

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I am trying to create a form with nested repeats that runs in Orbeon server. The idea is to have some elements that can be repeated and other elements inside the first one, that also can be repeated. i.e a block for inserting personal information (for several persons in a repeat) and for each person, we can add several phone numbers (also a repeat).

I have not found so much information about how to do it, and I suppose that I can create this: [Other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289799/orbeon-nested-repeats-cause-error-in-liferay-portlet) (but this example also does not work for me, even with the corrections exposed in the comments).

For testing I have created the next form:

```
<xh:html xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
xmlns:exf="http://www.exforms.org/exf/1-0"
xmlns:fb="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder"
xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
xmlns:odt="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/datatypes"
xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline"
xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:sql="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/sql"
xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
xmlns:xpl="java:org.orbeon.oxf.pipeline.api.FunctionLibrary"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms" xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude">
<xh:head>
    <xh:title>LoopInLoop</xh:title>
    <xf:model id="fr-form-model" xxf:expose-xpath-types="true">
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-metadata" xxf:readonly="true">
            <metadata>
                <application-name>DHszw</application-name>
                <form-name>LoopInLoop</form-name>
                <title xml:lang="en">LoopInLoop</title>
                <description xml:lang="en">Description of the form.</description>
            </metadata>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-instance">
            <form>
                <category-1>
                    <subcategory-1-1/>
                    <loop-group-0>
                        <loop-0>
                            <loop-group-0-0>
                                <loop-0-0>
                                <element-1-1-1/>
                                <element-1-1-2/>
                                </loop-0-0>
                            </loop-group-0-0>
                            <element-1-1-3/>
                            <element-1-1-4/>
                        </loop-0>
                    </loop-group-0>
                    <element-1-1-5/>
                </category-1>
            </form>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:bind id="fr-form-binds"
            ref="instance('fr-form-instance')" xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel">
            <xf:bind id="category-1-bind" name="category-1" ref="category-1">
                <xf:bind id="subcategory-1-1-bind"
                    name="subcategory-1-1" ref="subcategory-1-1"/>
                <xf:bind id="group-loop-0-bind"
                    name="group-loop-0-bind" ref="loop-group-0">
                    <xf:bind id="loop-0-bind" name="loop-0" ref="loop-0">
                        <xf:bind id="group-loop-0-0-bind"
                            name="group-loop-0-0-bind" ref="loop-group-0-0">
                            <xf:bind id="loop-0-0-bind"
                                name="loop-0-0" ref="loop-0-0">
                                <xf:bind id="element-1-1-1-bind"
                                name="element-1-1-1" ref="element-1-1-1"/>
                                <xf:bind id="element-1-1-2-bind"
                                name="element-1-1-2" ref="element-1-1-2"/>
                            </xf:bind>
                        </xf:bind>
                        <xf:bind id="element-1-1-3-bind"
                            name="element-1-1-3" ref="element-1-1-3" relevant="(../$element-1-1-2='no' )"/>
                        <xf:bind id="element-1-1-4-bind"
                            name="element-1-1-4" ref="element-1-1-4" relevant="(../$element-1-1-2='no' )"/>
                    </xf:bind>
                </xf:bind>
                <xf:bind id="element-1-1-5-bind"
                    name="element-1-1-5" ref="element-1-1-5" relevant="($element-1-1-4='no' )"/>
            </xf:bind>
        </xf:bind>
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-attachments">
            <attachments>
                <css filename="" mediatype="text/css" size=""/>
                <pdf filename="" mediatype="application/pdf" size=""/>
            </attachments>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="fr-form-resources" xxf:readonly="false">
            <resources>
                <resource xml:lang="en">
                    <category-1>
                        <label><![CDATA[new category]]></label>
                    </category-1>
                    <subcategory-1-1>
                        <label><![CDATA[<b>new sub-category</b><hr>]]></label>
                        <hint/>
                        <alert><![CDATA[]]></alert>
                    </subcategory-1-1>
                    <element-1-1-1>
                        <label><![CDATA[Add something]]></label>
                        <hint><![CDATA[]]></hint>
                        <alert/>
                    </element-1-1-1>
                    <element-1-1-2>
                        <label><![CDATA[More Loops?]]></label>
                        <hint><![CDATA[]]></hint>
                        <alert/>
                        <item>
                            <label><![CDATA[yes]]></label>
                            <value><![CDATA[yes]]></value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label><![CDATA[no]]></label>
                            <value><![CDATA[no]]></value>
                        </item>
                    </element-1-1-2>
                    <element-1-1-3>
                        <label><![CDATA[AddOtherThing]]></label>
                        <hint><![CDATA[]]></hint>
                        <alert/>
                    </element-1-1-3>
                    <element-1-1-4>
                        <label><![CDATA[MorewLoop2]]></label>
                        <hint><![CDATA[]]></hint>
                        <alert/>
                        <item>
                            <label><![CDATA[yes]]></label>
                            <value><![CDATA[yes]]></value>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                            <label><![CDATA[no]]></label>
                            <value><![CDATA[no]]></value>
                        </item>
                    </element-1-1-4>
                    <element-1-1-5>
                        <label><![CDATA[group.End]]></label>
                        <hint><![CDATA[]]></hint>
                        <alert/>
                    </element-1-1-5>
                </resource>
            </resources>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="fr-service-request-instance" xxf:exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
            <response/>
        </xf:instance>
       <xf:instance id="loop-0-template" xxf:readonly="true">
            <loop-0>
                <element-1-1-1/>
                <element-1-1-2/>
                <loop-0-0/>                    
            </loop-0>
        </xf:instance>
        <xf:instance id="loop-0-0-template" xxf:readonly="true">
            <loop-0-0>
                <element-1-1-3/>
                <element-1-1-4/>
            </loop-0-0>
        </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>
</xh:head>
<xh:body>
    <fr:view>
        <fr:body xmlns:dataModel="java:org.orbeon.oxf.fb.DataModel"
            xmlns:oxf="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors"
            xmlns:p="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/pipeline" xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl">
            <fr:section bind="category-1-bind" id="category-1-control">
                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/category-1/label"/>
                <xh:tr>
                    <xh:td>
                        <xf:output bind="subcategory-1-1-bind" id="subcategory-1-1-control">
                            <xf:label mediatype="text/html" ref="$form-resources/subcategory-1-1/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/subcategory-1-1/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                        </xf:output>
                    </xh:td>
                </xh:tr>
                <xf:group bind="group-loop-0-bind" id="group-loop-0-control">
                    <fr:grid bind="loop-0-bind" id="loop-0-control"
                        max="10" min="1"
                        origin="instance('loop-0-template')" repeat="true">
                        <xf:group bind="group-loop-0-0-bind" id="group-loop-0-0-control">
                            <fr:grid bind="loop-0-0-bind"
                                id="loop-0-0-control" max="10"
                                min="1"
                                origin="instance('loop-0-0-template')" repeat="true">
                                <xh:tr>
                                <xh:td>
                                <xf:input
                                bind="element-1-1-1-bind" id="element-1-1-1-control">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-1/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-1/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </xf:input>
                                </xh:td>
                                </xh:tr>
                                <xh:tr>
                                <xh:td>
                                <xf:select1
                                appearance="full"
                                bind="element-1-1-2-bind" id="element-1-1-2-control">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-2/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-2/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-2/item">
                                <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                                </xf:select1>
                                </xh:td>
                                </xh:tr>
                            </fr:grid>
                        </xf:group>
                        <xh:tr>
                            <xh:td>
                                <xf:input bind="element-1-1-3-bind" id="element-1-1-3-control">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-3/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-3/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                </xf:input>
                            </xh:td>
                        </xh:tr>
                        <xh:tr>
                            <xh:td>
                                <xf:select1 appearance="full"
                                bind="element-1-1-4-bind" id="element-1-1-4-control">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-4/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-4/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                                <xf:itemset ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-4/item">
                                <xf:label ref="label"/>
                                <xf:value ref="value"/>
                                </xf:itemset>
                                </xf:select1>
                            </xh:td>
                        </xh:tr>
                    </fr:grid>
                </xf:group>
                <fr:grid>
                    <xh:tr>
                        <xh:td>
                            <xf:output bind="element-1-1-5-bind" id="element-1-1-5-control">
                                <xf:label ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-5/label"/>
                                <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/element-1-1-5/hint"/>
                                <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
                            </xf:output>
                        </xh:td>
                    </xh:tr>
                </fr:grid>
            </fr:section>
        </fr:body>
    </fr:view>
</xh:body>
</xh:html>
```

But only the "nested repeat" is shown and not the "external" one.

The question is: Is it not implemented in Orbeon? Do It needs an specific syntax? Or is there any error that I cannot see?

I am using Orbeon 4.3.0.1.201308150213-CE.

**EDITED:**
I have changed the loops' "template" section with some corrections.

Comment: The scope of the application is to deploy a form in Orbeon that can be used for filling up the information, not only for representing stored data.

Comment: Is this for a form you created in Form Builder? At this point, Form Builder does not support nested repeats, so if you really need nested repeats you'll need to write the form by hand. Note that we're looking into supporting repeating sections in the near future which should handle use cases like this one.

Comment: The base of the form is created by the Form Builder, but the nested loop is created by hand. I am not sure if it is the correct way to do a nested loop or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting `<fr:grid>` isn't supported at this point. But we're planning to soon implement [support for nested sections](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1289), which should enable you to do what you're looking for.

Comment: I will wait until this characteristic will be implemented. Maybe for Orbeon 4.4?

Comment: That will be for after 4.4, maybe 4.5.

Comment: Nested sections seems to be a valid alternative for some cases.